# need screen shoot from map when user gave location and zoom level

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

**

- MapBox ScreenShoot issue:-

**

- i tried this link given by mapbox itself but did not find any thing
  useful.
- I also need some thing like this api in leaflet also. can
  somebody help
- [https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.satellite/1/17.34/86.324@1x.png?access_token="YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"](https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.satellite/1/17.34/86.324@1x.png?access_token=%22YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN%22)

Comment: Are you familiar with the Static Images API? https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/static-images/#retrieve-a-static-map-from-a-style

Comment: yes but i need satellite images

Comment: There’s a mapbox style you can use to generate equivalent requests through the modern api: https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/satellite-v9/static/0,0,0/500x500?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN